# Xcode 8 not opening project on start

Tags: xcode8, macos-sierra

I have a problem to open my project in Xcode 8 it's loading and not open. Yesterday It's opened but today not. I already deleted xcurdata folder, cleared DerivedData folder and deleted file **com.apple.dt.Xcode** in ~>/Library/Caches

Someone give me a light?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a problem with my icloud. My project was in Documents and every time that I install some framework with cocoapods, the Xcode stop to work, and load after icloud finish sync. I solved the problem putting the folder of project out of icloud.

Comment: dude you need to get a job on apple you saved my life

Answer (score 2):

This is in regards to an issue where you try to load a project in Xcode 8 after doing a migration to Swift 3 and all it does is stall and show the "Loading..." indicator in the Xcode status window?

Other methods of trying to correct this were:

1) Deleting ~/Library/Saved Application State/come.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState

2) Deleting /xcuserdata/ from Project.xcworkspace and Project.xcodeproj

3) Backing up the current story board, removing it from the project, recreating it, then cutting and pasting the contents from the old story board to the new story board.

I've tried all of the above to no avail. I've also upgraded to 8.1. I had a git folder inside my documents folder, so I am in the process of migrating that out my documents folder. Will try to load the project again after it's finished.

Just curious but did you have the "Optimize Mac Storage" option checked for iCloud sync? I did have it checked, I could see how this could cause a lot of issues with Xcode should your projects be stored in the documents folder. If some assets aren't getting touched for a long time, they are removed from the local drive and only stored in iCloud...

Comment: Wow... yep... This fixed it. What a nightmare dealing with this iCloud sync stuff... I tried to copy the folder that contained the project to my local drive but it kept hanging. I had to go into the project folder and copy out the items one at a time. This includes sub-folders though, so I didn't have to manually copy every file. The only thing I wound up not copying was the hidden .git folder. This folder was causing the "move" to hang every time.

Comment: Deleting ~/Library/Saved Application State/come.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState worked for me, thank!

Answer (score 2):

In my case with Xcode 8.2, I experienced slow and lots of hangs .. I am working with many projects .. the solution that so far seems to solves all such issues was to "disable" git repository creation during project creation .. I did recreate all of my projects without "git" repository because first: I am not experienced in using such "git" version control, and second: cause I manage versioning myself.